# Template an individual template per item in a list (Jinja2, Anisble)

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a Jinja template as follows

```
{% for cust, config in customers.items() %}
sim.gw.{{ cust|lower }}.mw.tport.type=udp
sim.gw.{{ cust|lower }}.mw.tport.udp.interface=lo
{% if config['accept'] is defined %}
sim.gw.{{ cust|lower }}.fix.accept_port={{ config['accept'] }}
{% endif %}
sim.gw.{{ cust|lower }}.fix.version=4.4
sim.gw.{{ cust|lower }}.fix.tagetsubid={{ config['type'] }}
sim.gw.{{ cust|lower }}.fix.sess.sendercompid0=CITIFX-UAT
sim.gw.{{ cust|lower }}.fix.sess.targetcompid0={{ cust }}-S-QUOTE
sim.gw.{{ cust|lower }}.fix.sess.sendercompid1=CITIFX-UAT
sim.gw.{{ cust|lower }}.fix.sess.targetcompid1={{ cust }}-S-TRADE
sim.gw.{{ cust|lower }}.fix.handler=libfixpythonhandler.so
sim.gw.{{ cust|lower }}.fix.py_script=pySimulator.py
sim.gw.{{ cust|lower }}.log={{ cust|lower }}.log
{% endfor %}
```

That is using variables found in this customer yml file:

```
BTG-VELOCITY:
    type: PBSTP
    accept: 1010
GFAM:
    type: PBSTP
    connect: 1010
ONEZERO2:
    type: TRADESTREAM
GUANFABANK:
    type: FXSIM
MAINBANK:
    type: FXSIM
TYPOBANK:
    type: TRADESTREAM
TEST-BANK:
    type: PBSTP
    connect: 32620
    accept: 33620
WEAKBANK:
    type: TRADESTREAM
```

And when I run my playbook I am using this configuration:

```
- include_vars:
    file: /home/vagrant/stunnelSimAnsPractice/roles/ns16/vars/customers.yml
    name: customers
- name: templating
  template:
    src: /home/vagrant/stunnelSimAnsPractice/roles/ns16/templates/simulator.properties.j2
    dest: /home/vagrant/stunnelSimAnsPractice/roles/ns16/sessions/{{ item }}/simulator.properties
    owner: root
    group: root
  register: result
  with_items: "{{ customers }}"
```

My problem is that I wish to create an individual 'simulator.properties' for each customer. At present my playbook generates one long simulator.properties containing all properties for all customers and places the same file in each customer directory. The output should unique to each customer so that each directory contains only the given customer's properties. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `{% for...` and `{% endfor...` lines from your template, because you want only one customer in resulting file. And execute template task as follows:

```
- name: templating
  template:
    src: /home/vagrant/stunnelSimAnsPractice/roles/ns16/templates/simulator.properties.j2
    dest: /home/vagrant/stunnelSimAnsPractice/roles/ns16/sessions/{{ item }}/simulator.properties
    owner: root
    group: root
  register: result
  vars:
    cust: "{{ item.key }}"
    config: "{{ item.value }}"
  with_dict: "{{ customers }}"
```